# Bad Request (Error 400) getting static map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to get a static image from a map and put on my Android layout. So, looking for it I've found a code talking about Google Static Maps. Awesome! I've tried some URLs on my PC and it's working perfectly!

But my problem was when I've put the URL in Android to test it. WHen I try to get the input stream (the image), it gives me FileNotFoundExceptioin, because when I tried to connect, it threw me a **Bad Request (error 400)**

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... stringURL) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringURL[0]);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mapView.setImageBitmap(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

[String for test](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=S%C3%A3o%20Paulo,%20Brazil&zoom=15&size=720x720&sensor=false)

Do I need a key for this?? Why don't I need a key for doing it in a browser?

Comment: Could you post the url `ImageLoadingTask` gets? Maybe log it before you do anything. Google will return 400 if it doesn't like something about your url and you might be constructing it wrong.

Comment: Nevermind I see you posted it. Make sure you encode the url... that "ã" seems a little bit fishy to me. If you just put that url into Chrome, it does the dirty work of making sure it's URL Safe. With a URL I don't think it does.

Comment: Yes, it is!! That's the problem. I tried with "Brazil" and it's working perfectly! THanks

Comment: Should i post this as an answer?

Comment: Yes..do you know how can I format this string to be good for static maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you're sending to Google has a strange character in it. Before sending it, run a `URLEncode.encode()` on it or if you're always showing São Paulo you could say "Sao Paulo" and let Google figure it out, or "S%C3%A3o%20Paulo". Personally I think the first one is less error prone but it's up to you.